# Are there any routers supporting client-side VPN?

Tags: vpn, router

What I'm asking for is basically what the title says. I need a router that can forward all the data-traffic it receives through a VPN tunnel. Have Google'd a little but I can't seam to find a topic which the links to potential products still are active.

The parameters to the specific VPN it is going to be used with is as follows:

[image: VPN parameters]

Sorry it is in Norwegian, but you should be able recognize the relevant parameters like encryption and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more like "which non end user router does it NOT". pretty much every router that is made for professionals will handle routing over VPN's.

Your VPN is totally insecure, btw. - PPTP encryption is crackable in 20 minutes due to a handshake error. MS recommends getting rid of it.

Comment: Yes, I know, but i do not control the VPN. The VPN is just in place from my superiors to somewhat proxy us, for filtering purposes. Can you suggest a router that would suffice for my needs? Preferably a D-Link.

Comment: Pretty much anything from Mikrotik, but those are pro routers - yo ubetter know what you are doing there, or you WILL get lost in the UI or command line.